# How to obtain the main activity name in application?

Tags: android, android-activity

How to get the main activity in third party applications of system?

```
PackageManager  pm= getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
for (PackageInfo pi : packs) {
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("icon", pi.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm));
map.put("appName", pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
map.put("packageName", pi.packageName);
}
```

I know how to get the package name. But do not know how to obtain the name of main activity.

I use pi.activities[0].name. It still obtain null pointer.

Anyone’s idea is very appreciate.

Comment: isn't your app name stored in strings.xml? Which is also used in the manifest.

Comment: @StephanCelis OP asked how to get the name of the main activity in a **3rd party application**, not his own application (ie: without source code).

Comment: @David Wasser, good point! missed that detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(pi.packageName);
```

This will give you launch intent, if you print it you will see the launcher intent along with the main activity.

If you want to show only **activity** that can be launched from your device launcher then you need to put a filter for Category **Launcher**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
final PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai;
try {
    ai = pm.getApplicationInfo( this.getPackageName(), 0);
 } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
 ai = null;
}
final String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "unknown)");
```

Comment: OP asked how to get the name of the main activity in a **3rd party application**, not his own application. This code will only work for your own application.

Comment: @DavidWasser Sorry, I have altered the answer.

Comment: OP asked for the name of the **main activity**, not the name of the application. Your answer is still wrong.